# Prevent automatic compression of text in NSTextField without auto layout

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, nstextfield

In the latest Xcode, some NSTextfields have started automatically visually compressing values that are too long to be displayed.  This is happening in xibs that have not been converted to autolayout.  I understand that if I convert the design to use autolayout, the "compression resistance" setting would control this, but I am hoping not to have to convert to autolayout at this time.  Is there some way to simply return to the old, default behavior?